# Serve up file from outside wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating an ASP.NET4.5 website to ASP.NET 5.  One function we had returned images off the hard disk from an absolute location.  The files arent stored within the web directory.  Previously this worked fine, with the following code:

```
public ActionResult GetVideoImage(string serialNumber, int videoEntryId)
{
    try
    {
        var serial = Device.FriendlySerialNumberToNumericalSerialNumber(serialNumber);

        var entry = this.service.GetVideoEntry(serial, videoEntryId);

        if (entry != null && System.IO.File.Exists(entry.FirstVideoFrameLocation.LocalPath))
        {
            return this.File(entry.FirstVideoFrameLocation.LocalPath, "image/jpeg"); // adjust content type appropriately
        }
    }

    return this.Redirect("/content/noimage.png");
}
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work anymore and throws an exception.  From what I can tell its because `this.File` now takes a `virtualPath` rather than an absolute one so balks at the idea of serving a file from outside of its web directory.

- How can I get around this?
- Also is `ActionResult` still the best
  return type for this?

Comment: Can you move those files into the webroot? The reason this changed is, I believe, a security concern: if the website is limited to serving things under the web directory, then it's that much harder for an attack on the website to return random data from the rest of the computer.

Comment: cant you read the images as a stream and return that stream?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Unfortunately not, on my dev machine its just in a different folder.  In production the files could be served from a different machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on a MS thread [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/2011115.aspx?How%20to%20download%20a%20file%20from%20a%20path%20in%20asp%20net%20vnext%20) that links to a [ASP github commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/a2023d35ee2805435e89a1b59cc6a7a78bc79307).

Long story short there are new classes available in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace that allow the thing I'm looking for.  I specifically chose `PhysicalFileResult` which works as expected